# Which hash-tag should we use in social media?

Tags: latex-misc, tex-general

Now that facebook is using hash-tags I wondered what users had to say about #LaTeX, but to my surprise (well, it was obvious...), I found plenty of stuff related to latex clothing...

The question is: Does anybody can come out with a good enough, representative and easy to remember hash-tag we could use in social media ?

First hint: Hash-tags are not case sensitive -->  #LaTeX = #latex

Comment: I'd say #tex, but it might confuse Tex Willer's fans.

Comment: tex is also a brand...

Comment: I'd say let's just use #LaTeX (capitalized, even if it does not make any difference when searching a capitalized hashtag looks different from the non capitalized counterpart) and learn to live with #latex people :)

Comment: @dcmst I don't think it is a good idea... There will be tons of unrelated LaTeX stuff, much much much more than LaTeX related. You might spend a lot of time just to filter what you want

Comment: Good question, but I think it belongs on meta.  Also, could you include some reference to Facebook's use of hashtags?

Comment: Oh well, some of the unrelated stuff is quite erm... interesting, so... (please note mine wasn't a serious proposal, I don't even use Twitter nor FB)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Definitely not meta – this question is in no way *about* the site tex.sx. Just because it is a non-technical question doesn’t mean it belongs on meta. It might not be a great fit for our site (too argumentative / not constructive), but it is on topic. **Voting to reopen.** (Even if it’s only to close it again as *not constructive*.)

Comment: @doncherry I agree the question is not about the site.  For some reason I though meta was a good place for it (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community maybe?).

Answer (score 4):

Since this topic straddles the on-/off-topic boundary, I thought I'd post a CW "answer" so that the community could keep the conversation open, if interested. Here are some suggestions:

1. `#tex`
2. `#latexproject`
3. `#knuthtex`
4. `#typographyintex`; `#textypography`; `#typesettingintex`; `#textypesetting`

I think the use of `#latex` is ambiguous since it may also refer to [a natural/synthetic substance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latex).

Comment: If one were to avoid ambiguous tags, what would happen to `#windows` and `#apple`!